# Why button style change when i added programmatically?

Tags: android, xml

I have a list of button in a scrollview, but when i add some other button programmatically the style is different and i don't know why.
As we can see in the next picture, buttons added are more darker, and when i click on the button, the background of the button become blue.
But my default button is a dark grey.

There is the capture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q07WR.png)

The button "6" is the XML button add. The other are added programmatically.

There is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/diese">


    <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

            <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="700dp" >

               <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/one"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="1" />
                </TableRow>
```

There is my code which add button:

TableLayout sv = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

```
    TableLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,2200,500);

    sv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    View view = findViewById(R.id.diese);

    Diese d1 = new Diese(1,"test");
    d1.addDieseToXml(sv,this);
    Diese d2 = new Diese(2,"Coucou");
    d2.addDieseToXml(sv,this);
```

Thx a lot. The context "this" reference to my ButtonActivity.

Comment: Maybe the button is .setActivated(true); or is focused for some reason, i prefer gridView to create Buttons programmatically

Answer (score 0):

you should show us your style file, and Diese class ? I feel like it's a style problem.

However given the informations provided i'm almost sure that "addDieseToXml" or the Diese class itself define the button style, and you don't apply that style to your xml button (as you stated that dark grey is the color you wanted).

Thus, i'd suggest you to apply a style to your button with

```
style="@style/YourStyle"
```

directly in the XML button code.

Other option is to apply this style to all your activity buttons (if you want so) by changing your theme, adding

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/YourStyle</item>
```

Comment: I didn't define style for button... I find no clue to my problem ><

Comment: did you define a base theme for your application ?

Comment: No, i do nothing special when i add a button in xml. They are grey and draker grey when they are clicked, and when i added them programmatically, they are grey but blue when i clicked on